# 'Windows - No Disk' Error c0000013

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I am getting an error entitled "Windows - No Disk" where the body of the message is:

"Exception Processing Message c0000013 Parameters 75b6bf7c 4 75b6bf7c 75b6bf7c "

Anyone knows why?

I have not added any new hardware. I did install iTunes 10.6.0.40 after which I was asked to reboot and then the error message started popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced SATA cable that connected motherboard with hard drive and the error has gone away.